# Devise: Forbidden Attributes Error on Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have set up devise. I added database authentication, only in the first instance. I was able to fill out the form and add it to my db. I then added omniauth and now, when I try to register using the form, rather than the social media options, I get a forbidden attributes error.

My view is:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal", :method => 'get' %>
    </li>


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Request an invite</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>

              <div class="facebookauth"> <%= link_to "Register with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></div>
               <br />
                <% end -%>
                <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
               <div class="linkedinauth"> <%= link_to "Register with LinkedIn", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %></div>
                <br />

            <% end -%>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">


            <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs" style="padding-left:15%; text-align:left;">
                <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-actions" style="padding-left:15%; padding-top:5%; text-align:left;">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Register" %><% end %>

              </div>





          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



<% end %>
```

My application controller has this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit( :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit( :email, :password, :remember_me) }
end
```

I have just tried adding this to my user/registrations_controller, but it does not help.

```
def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
        end
```

I'm wondering if its because I don't have fields in my database for password or password confirmation? I have 'encrypted password'.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you add `before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?` in your `applications_controller.rb` ?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what happened. I added private def params for user with the input fields - i thought they were standard in devise.